# In TypeScript, how to express that a callback will only be called if a condition is true?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a function

```js
function doIf(condition: boolean, callback: () => void) {
  if (condition) {
    callback();
  }
}
```

is it possible to have typescript infer that `myVar` is defined within the scope of the callback?

```js
const myVar: string | undefined = maybeGetString();

doIf(myVar !== undefined, () => {
  console.log(myVar.toLowerCase()); // 'myVar' is possibly 'undefined'.
});
```

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to conditionally call some callback, but you only want the condition to exist within the callback?  So basically `doIf(true, () => {const str = maybeGetString(); if (str) { console.log(str.toLowerCase())}})`

Comment: It's not possible and I don't even see how it could be implemented easily; it's the same basic issue as in [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  There's a feature request for this at [ms/TS#49395](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49395) but there's almost no engagement on it.  So the answer is: "no, sorry".  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @Jake, yes that is correct.

Comment: @jcalz "no, sorry" is a perfectly valid answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't currently possible and it's not clear if it ever will be.  You'll probably want to work around it by manually asserting the types as needed.

---

TypeScript currently doesn't have much support for [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) that crosses function boundaries.  Generally speaking it would be computationally intractable to try to do that automatically... the compiler could conceivably "inline" the implementation of `doIf()` like

```
if (/* condition */ myVar) {
    (/* callback */() => {
        console.log(myVar.toLowerCase()); // okay
    })();
},
```

but that would get very expensive very quickly.  This general limitation of control flow across function boundaries is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998), and it looks like there are always going to be situations that don't work as desired.

And while there are a few ways to explicitly annotate functions as having implications on control ploy, such as [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) and [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), unfortunately neither of these give you the handle you need here.

There is an existing open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#49395](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49395) to allow annotating function parameters with assertion-predicate-like modifiers, so that you could maybe write

```
// NOT VALID TS, DON'T TRY THIS:
declare function doIf(
  condition: boolean, 
  callback: (asserts: condition is true) => void
): void;
```

and the compiler would understand that `condition` has been narrowed to `true` inside of the callback body.  (Who knows about the actual syntax for such a feature; I'm imagining an `asserts` parameter acting like a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) in the sense that it gets erased from the emitted JavaScript, and only serves to specify the type of something inside the function body.)  But there's very little engagement with that issue so I don't imagine it will be acted upon anytime soon.

---

Until and unless that happens, you'll just need to work around it, unfortunately.  You could use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like

```
console.log((myVar as string).toLowerCase());
```

or, specifically in the case of asserting `myVar` as not being `undefined`, you could use [the non-null assertion operator (`!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-):

```
console.log(myVar!.toLowerCase());
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-DBEIU0Nh1HhbR9eTGiGCoTCvGRfUGIzGE1dpjqMLhLTaS0c+TTqMzGJzl2SsiAA)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the thorough, in-depth explanation! I'd give you more upvotes if I could 

Answer (score 2):

You can use the non-null assertion operator to tell typescript that something is not null or undefined. (only do this if you are absolutely sure something can never be null or undefined) You can read the typescript documentation for more information here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator

with the non-null assertion operator the code that changes would look like this:

```
myVar!.toLowerCase()
```

Comment: Upvote as this is the way I worked around the issue in the end. However, I will not mark this as an answer as it does not address the question fully.